# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user although the same user name password combination works with mysql_connect

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using PDO to connect to MySQL database. The code works perfect when run in local host. However when I transfer the code to web server (of course I have changed the user name and password accordingly) the code does not work. It gives the following error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'xxx_xxxxx'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

When I test connection using old deprecated API - mysql_connect() with same user name password combination, it works perfect, so I know that the user name password combination is right.

Here is my relevant code

```
try {
    $dsn = "mysql:dbname=company_dbname; host=localhost";
    $user = "company_dbuser";
    $password = "MyPassword";
    $options = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, $options);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Try mysqli ? Also try without options ?

Comment: Have u check host ??

Comment: Your DSN should contain no spaces.

Comment: @Mehdi I think that bug has been fixed. I just tried on my server and spaces caused no problem.

Comment: @Barmar what version are you using?

Comment: @Mehdi Removing space didn't solve the issue. I am getting same error.

Comment: @Mehdi PHP 5.4.45, don't know how to determine PDO version.

Comment: Are you sure that the SQL Server is on localhost on live server? Most in my experience are not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I am able to solve the problem
Here is my edited code

```
try {
    $dsn = "mysql:dbname=company_dbname; host=localhost";
    $user = 'company_dbuser';
    $password = 'MyPassword';
    $options = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, $options);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Please check $user and $password assignment - instead of double quote I assigned single quoted value.